# Dynamics Crm 365 On Premises Reports parameter get disable on Farm server?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am new to CRM. My report is running fine when i use particular server link like,

```
Shcrm01:6623/SPCRMDEV
```

But, when i use farm instead of particular server name as we have ten servers on which crm deployed report parameter gets disable our link is like,

```
SPCRM:6623/SPCRMDEV
```

Here are disabled Parameters

[image]

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you online? Are you running the report inside CRM?